# Give a second name to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code source that contains a long variable name (`postCustomThumbnailsScrollerHeight`).

I don't want to rename this variable for the whole code source so that I easily continue the project, but to have a shorthand of its name. I tried following solution (which works) at the first declaration of the variable, but I am not sure if it is the correct way to do so. I have a different color of `d` in IDE:

```
var postCustomThumbnailsScrollerHeight= d= $('.post-scroller').outerHeight();
```

I am seeking by this question your usual expert advice.

Comment: Are you expecting that if you change the value of one that the other will change too?

Comment: This creates a global variable `d`.

Comment: jquery doesn't have "references". You can trivially do `var x = longvarname` and use `x` everywhere, but it'll be TWO different variables, and they won't keep each other's values in sync

Comment: Let me enrich that, JAVASCRIPT has no "references" :)

Comment: @FelixKling, exaclty, IDE changes  its color to the color of gloabal variables.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces: then you are out of luck. Assigning a new value to a variable never changes the value of another variable.

Comment: When learning a new computer language, one of the first things you need to know is whether it assigns (and passes) by reference or by value. In javaScript, the answer is both, depending on the member's type.

Comment: @SolracRagnarockradio, I see now, thank you. I need the two names pointing the same variable and the value being synchronized

Comment: @Roamer-1888: no, you are confusing *pass-by-reference* with how object are represented. Those are two different kinds of references. JavaScript is always pass by value. Pass by reference means I can do this: `var foo = 42; var bar = foo; bar = 21;` and `foo` is now 21 as well. This is not possible in JS, no matter the value of the variable.

Comment: I feel like there's probably a whole load of reasons you shouldn't do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/m66yqbr9/).

Comment: @Roamer-1888: I recommend to read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy to get more insight into the matter. Put differently, objects are presented *as* references, but they are **not** passed *by* reference (and that's a big difference).

Comment: I don't get the closing here. How is this question *off-topic* ?

Comment: Constructive comments I've seen before disappeared too... Was there a war in comments here ?

Comment: @FelixKling, sorry Felix, I was in a bad place yesterday and should have stayed away from SO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, this isn't really correct: you're not **declaring** the `d` variable, only **assigning** to it, and thus

1. making it global (which may or not be desired)
2. making your code incompatible with [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Converting_mistakes_into_errors)

Here's a solution:

```
var d = $('.post-scroller').outerHeight(),
    postCustomThumbnailsScrollerHeight = d;
```

Note that this should only be done for readability/typing issues, not for downloaded script size: minifiers should be used for that latter goal.

Be also careful that you're not making an alias, but really two variables. If you assign to one, you won't change the other one. It's hard to give a definite advice without more information but the usual solution is to have namespaced object:

Assuming you have a struct

```
myApp.thumbnailScrollers.postCustom = {height:...
```

then you would just assign that latter object to a local variable in a module or function:

```
var s = myApp.thumbnailScrollers.postCustom
```

In *this* case, changing `s.height` would also change `myApp.thumbnailScrollers.postCustom.height`.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces I suspect you'd be interested in modules and namespaces. Here's a start: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have different color because in this case `b` it's global variable.

As for my opinion will be better to write all definitions on different lines:

```
var postCustomThumbnailsScrollerHeight = $('.post-scroller').outerHeight();
var d = postCustomThumbnailsScrollerHeight;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.

Answer (score 0):

Although JavaScript doesn't natively support references, you can stimulate them using code such as this:

```
function d(){
    return postCustomThumbnailsScrollerHeight;
}
```

Then just use `d()` everywhere. It's not very elegant, but as far as I know it's the only way to get a reference in JavaScript.

Answer (score -2):

Do you have a problem declaring that var in the next line?
You could just do:

```
var postCustomThumbnailsScrollerHeight = $('.post-scroller').outerHeight();
var d = postCustomThumbnailsScrollerHeight;
```